# Independent Bernoulli r.v.s and times of success.

Tags: probability-theory

> Times of successes. Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be independent Bernoulli variables with the same success probability $p$. Define, for each $k$ in $\mathbb N^*$, the time of $k$th success by
> $$T_k(\omega) = \inf \{ n \ge 1: S_n(\omega) \ge k\}, \quad \omega \in \Omega. $$
> Note that this yields $T_k(\omega) = + \infty$ if $S_n(\omega) < k$ for all $n$. Show that $T_k$ is a random variable for each $k$ in $N^*$. Show that, for integers $n \ge k$,
> $$\mathbb P\{T_k = n\} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}p^kq^{n-k},$$
> $$\mathbb P\{T_k \le n\} = \sum_{j=k}^n \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}p^jq^{n-j}.$$
> Show, in particular, that $T_k < \infty$ almost surely and, therefore, that $\lim S_n = +\infty$ almost surely.

To show that $T_k$ is r.v., note that $\{T_k = n\} = \{S_{n-1} = k-1\} \cap \{X_n = 1\} \in \sigma\{X_1, X_2, ... , X_n\}$ for every $n$. For the second part, since $S_{n-1}$ and $X_n$ are independent, $\mathbb P\{T_k = n\} = \mathbb P\{S_{n-1} = k-1\} \mathbb P\{X_n = 1\}$. I am stuck with the third part. For $k$, the events $\{T_k = n\}_n$ are independent (correct?). Then,
$$\mathbb P\{T_k \le n\} = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb P\{T_k = j\} = \sum_{j=k}^n \frac{(j-1)!}{(k-1)!(j-k)!}p^kq^{j-k}.$$
How is this equal to the one described in the question? For the last part, I think it is enough to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\{S_n = k-1\} = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The events $\{T_k=n\}_n$ are not independent: Since $\{T_k=n+1\}$ and $\{T_k=n\}$ are disjoint the probability of both occurring is always zero regardless of the probabilities of the individual events. This is however not relevant in the
derivation of your last formula which seems correct:

$$\tag{correct}\mathbb P\{T_k \le n\} = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb P\{T_k = j\} = \sum_{j=k}^n \frac{(j-1)!}{(k-1)!(j-k)!}p^kq^{j-k}.$$

What disturbs me is that the second formula you are trying to show seems wrong:

$$\tag{looks wrong}\mathbb P\{T_k \le n\} = \sum_{j=k}^n \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}p^jq^{n-j}.$$

Assume $n=2$. Then

- $\mathbb P\{T_1=1\}=\mathbb P\{S_1=1\}=\mathbb P\{X_1=1\}=p\,;$
- $\mathbb P\{T_1=2\}=\mathbb P(\{S_1=0\}\cap\{S_2=1\})=\mathbb P(\{X_1=0\}\cap\{X_2=1\})=(1-p)p\,;$

Therefore,

$$
\mathbb P\{T_1\le 2\}=(1-p)p+p\,.
$$

The formula that looks wrong however says
$$
\mathbb P\{T_1\le 2\}=p(1-p)+p^\color{red}{2}\,.
$$